# if else not working in php [nested]

Tags: php

Im making a product registration form. Im trying to make a checkup for blank form or same product code before running a query. the problem is that, when i run the page. even when i fill in the form for `inputNamaProduk` and i left other blank, i get the `$message` for blank `inputNamaProduk`

```
if(strlen($_POST['inputNamaProduk'])>=0)
    {
        $form = true;
        $message = '<p>Sila Isi Nama Produk.</p>';

    }
else
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['inputSpesifikasi'])>=0)
            {
                $form = true;
                $message = '<p>Sila Isi Spesifikasi Produk.</p>';
            }

        else

            {   
                if ($dn==0)
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
                (product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,price,product_img,product_img_name) 
                VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$harga','$image','$name')");

                else
                    {
                        $form = true;
                        $message = '<p>Sila Pilih Kod Produk Lain.</p>';
                    }
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you have a >= 0 this basically means if strlen($_POST['inputNamaProduk']) > 0 ( if you enter something in this field then it will show you the message ) Sila Isi Nama Produk.

try this

```
if(strlen($_POST['inputNamaProduk']) < 1)
    {
        $form = true;
        $message = '<p>Sila Isi Nama Produk.</p>';

    }
else
    {
        if(strlen($_POST['inputSpesifikasi'])>=0)
            {
                $form = true;
                $message = '<p>Sila Isi Spesifikasi Produk.</p>';
            }

        else

            {   
                if ($dn==0)
                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
                (product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,price,product_img,product_img_name) 
                VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$harga','$image','$name')");

                else
                    {
                        $form = true;
                        $message = '<p>Sila Pilih Kod Produk Lain.</p>';
                    }
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `strlen($_POST['inputNamaProduk']) >= 0` is always true.

Because this means `>` Greather than and `<` Less than.

It should be like below,

```
if (strlen($_POST['inputNamaProduk']) < 1) {
    $form = true;
}
```

You can also use `empty` to check whether the input field is empty or not like below.

```
if (empty($_POST['inputNamaProduk'])) {
    $form = true;
    $message = '<p>Sila Isi Nama Produk.</p>';
}
else {
    if (empty($_POST['inputSpesifikasi'])) {
        $form = true;
        $message = '<p>Sila Isi Spesifikasi Produk.</p>';
    }
    else {
        if ($dn == 0) $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
                    VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$harga','$image','$name')");
        else {
            $form = true;
            $message = '<p>Sila Pilih Kod Produk Lain.</p>';
        }
    }
}
```